# How to send email to a specific list item

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to for a user to reply to a workflow(generated on create item) email and make that email content attach to that particular list item? 
This list is a issue tracking list and part of a helpdesk system. What I'm trying to achieve is for helpdesk and submitting user to be able to have a dialog about the list item and for this dialog to be logged within the item.

Comment: I don't know about lists, but I'm aware that this is possible with Discussionboards.

Comment: Check out this article, may be it will help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/733164/How-to-create-HelpDesk-on-SharePoint-Online